# R Corrgram showing frequency pairs that have zero abundance 'Pie Method'

Tags: r, graphics, correlation

I am attempting to reproduce a corrgram (below; Fig 1) using [Zuur et al (2010)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2009.00001.x/abstract) reproducible R code (below) showing the frequency with which pairs of water- bird species both have zero abundance. The colour and the amount that a circle has been filled correspond to the proportion of observa- tions with double zeros. The diagonal running from bottom left to the top right represents the percentage of observations of a variable equal to zero..

I have adapted this code for my data but I am experiencing the same problem after running the code for both datasets. When I run the code, the circles inside the corrgram are not filling in, and remain empty (below; Figure 2).

I am however confused as to why I am hitting this problem. If anyone has a solution as to why this occurs, then I would be deeply appreciative for your help.

**Data: By Zuur et al (2010)**

The data is too large to include with this post but it can be found in the [supporting materials section](http://**Data:%20By%20Zuur%20et%20al%20(2010)**%20%20%20The%20data%20is%20too%20large%20to%20include%20with%20this%20post%20but%20it%20can%20be%20found%20in%20the%20supporting%20materials%20section%20here%20[supplementary%20materials][1]) called **ElphickBirdData.txt**

**R Code: Zuur et al (2010)**

```
RiceField <- read.table(file="ElphickBirdData.txt", header = TRUE)

AllS <- c(
 "TUSW",     "GWFG",     "WHGO",     "CAGO",     "MALL",
 "GADW",     "GWTE",     "CITE",     "UNTE",     "AMWI",     "NOPI",
 "NOSH",     "RIDU",     "CANV",     "BUFF",     "WODU",     "RUDU",
 "EUWI",     "UNDU",     "PBGB",     "SORA",     "COOT",     "COMO",
 "AMBI",     "BCNH",     "GBHE",     "SNEG",     "GREG",     "WFIB",
 "SACR",     "AMAV",     "BNST",     "BBPL",     "KILL",     "LBCU",
 "GRYE",     "LEYE",     "LBDO",     "SNIP",     "DUNL",     "WESA",
 "LESA",     "PEEP",     "RUFF",     "UNSH",     "RBGU",     "HEGU",
 "CAGU",     "GUSP")

#Determine species richness
Richness <- colSums(RiceField[,AllS] > 0, na.rm = TRUE)

#Remove all covariates
Birds  <- RiceField[,AllS]

#To reduce the of variables in the figure, we only used the
#20 species that occured at more than 40 sites.
#As a result, N = 20. Else it becomes a mess.
 Birds2 <- Birds[, Richness > 40]
 N <- ncol(Birds2)

AllNames <- names(Birds2)
A <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = N)

 for (i in 1:N){
    for (j in 1:N){
 A[i,j] <- sum(RiceField[,AllS[i]]==0  & RiceField[,AllS[j]]==0,  na.rm=TRUE)
     }}


A1 <- A/2035
print(A1, digits = 2)
rownames(A1) <- AllNames
colnames(A1) <- AllNames


 library(lattice)
 library(RColorBrewer)

panel.corrgram.2 <- function(x, y, z, subscripts, at = pretty(z), scale = 0.8, ...)
{
require("grid", quietly = TRUE)
x <- as.numeric(x)[subscripts]
y <- as.numeric(y)[subscripts]
z <- as.numeric(z)[subscripts]
zcol <- level.colors(z, at = at, ...)
for (i in seq(along = z))
{
lims <- range(0, z[i])
tval <- 2 * base::pi *
  seq(from = lims[1], to = lims[2], by = 0.01)
  grid.polygon(x = x[i] + .5 * scale * c(0, sin(tval)),
             y = y[i] + .5 * scale * c(0, cos(tval)),
             default.units = "native",
             gp = gpar(fill = zcol[i]))
 grid.circle(x = x[i], y = y[i], r = .5 * scale,
            default.units = "native")
     }
     }

  levelplot(A1,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,
            at=do.breaks(c(0.5,1.01),101),
            panel=panel.corrgram.2,
            scales=list(x=list(rot=90)),
            colorkey=list(space="top"),
            col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("red","white","blue")))

   #Grey colours
   levelplot(A1.bats,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,
    at=do.breaks(c(0.5,1.01),101),
    panel=panel.corrgram.2,
    scales=list(x=list(rot=90)),
    colorkey=list(space="top"),
    col.regions=colorRampPalette(c(grey(0.8),grey(0.5),grey(0.2))))
```

**Figure 1.**
[image]
**Figure 2**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem is that `grid.circles` daubs `grid.polygon` with white. You can solved it by changing order of `grid.circle` and `grid.polygon` (or add `gp = gpar(fill=NA)` to `grid.circle()` ).

```
panel.corrgram.2.2 <- function(x, y, z, subscripts, at = pretty(z), scale = 0.8, ...)
{
    require("grid", quietly = TRUE)
    x <- as.numeric(x)[subscripts]
    y <- as.numeric(y)[subscripts]
    z <- as.numeric(z)[subscripts]
    zcol <- level.colors(z, at = at, ...)
    for (i in seq(along = z))
    {
        lims <- range(0, z[i])
        tval <- 2 * base::pi *
            seq(from = lims[1], to = lims[2], by = 0.01)
        grid.circle(x = x[i], y = y[i], r = .5 * scale,        # change the order
                    default.units = "native")
        grid.polygon(x = x[i] + .5 * scale * c(0, sin(tval)),
                     y = y[i] + .5 * scale * c(0, cos(tval)),
                     default.units = "native",
                     gp = gpar(fill = zcol[i]))
    }
}

levelplot(A1,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,
    at=do.breaks(c(0.5,1.01),101),
    panel=panel.corrgram.2.2,
    scales=list(x=list(rot=90)),
    colorkey=list(space="top"),
    col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("red","white","blue")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much cuttlefish, your help is greatly appreciated. Wonderful!!! One question: Would you have any ideas  what the value 2035 stands for in **A1 <- A/2035**?. If you happen to know, then many many thanks in advance.

Comment: @AliceHobbs; `nrow(RiceField)` is 2035. Authors did 2035 observations (see figure 7 in original paper).

Comment: You might also look at the corrgram package, which has a function panel.pie to draw pies.